# Compare two arrays in PowerShell

Tags: arrays, sql-server, xml, powershell, compare

I try to compare two arrays, but it won't work.

```
#System.Data.DataSet -> $Dataset.Tables.Identifier
#System.Xml.XmlElement -> $xmlarray

#$Arraytemp = $xmlarray | Where {$Dataset.Tables.Identifier -NotContains $xmlarray.myid}
$Arraytemp = $xmlarray | Where {$Dataset.Tables.Identifier -NotContains $x_}

Write-Host "Compared Results"
$Arraytemp | ft
Write-Host "XML Results"
$xmlarray | ft
Write-Host "SQL Results"
$Dataset.Tables.Identifier | ft
```

I read a XML result in an array `$xmlarray`. It contains the coloumn `myid` as a unique identifier (and other coloumns).
I read a MS SQL result in an array in `$Dataset.Tables.Identifier`, it only contains a unique identifier.
The SQL result contains only a part of the XML array. So I want to know, which rows are the difference, because I want to `INSERT` them in the database.

When I check the result with `Write-Host` the results looks good. When I compare them, nothing happens.

SQL is `System.Data.DataSet`.
SQL is `System.Xml.XmlElement`.

May be the dataformat is not compatible?

Comment: `$x_` -> `$_.myid`

Comment: Correct. That works! Thank you....